Unable to unit test Azure Durable Function in Python v2 Programming Model
I'm really struggling to write unit tests for an Azure Durable Function in Python.
This is the code:
@bp.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 12 * * *", arg_name="timer")
@bp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def my_func(timer: func.TimerRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> None:
    await client.start_new("durable_orchestrator")

And this is my test:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_extract_data_timer():
    mock_timer = create_autospec(func.TimerRequest, instance=True)
    mock_timer_request.past_due = False

    mock_starter = AsyncMock(spec=df.DurableOrchestrationClient)
    mock_starter.start_new = AsyncMock(return_value="test")

    result = await my_func(mock_timer_request, mock_starter)
    mock_starter.start_new.assert_called_with("durable_orchestrator")

When I run this I get the following error:

E       TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

And interestingly enough when I remove the decorators (@bp.timer_trigger & @bp.durable_client_input) the test passes no problem.
Something I've noticed is that without the decorators the function signature is:
def my_func(
    timer: TimerRequest,
    starter: DurableOrchestrationClient
) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, None]

And as soon as the decorators are added I get:
async def my_func(
    timer: TimerRequest,
    starter: DurableOrchestrationClient
) -> None

===== UPDATE =====
This issue opened in GitHub indicates that testing Azure Durable Functions is an on-going issue, and it has been open for 9 months already. Not sure what the plan from the Azure team is on this.

The second one doesn't work, same error. The first one I think might need a bit more work, because you can't mock and autospec something.

I have faced similar issue and I agree that it is working for me too after removing decorators. In below code,  i have created another function and tested and not using decorators. I too think that it is a bug.
import sys
import os
import azure.durable_functions as df
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock as cho, create_autospec
import azure.functions as func
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from function_app import tst  

async def test_start_durable_orchestration():
    rc = create_autospec(func.TimerRequest)
    rc.past_due = False
    rith = cho(spec=df.DurableOrchestrationClient)
    rith.start_new = cho(return_value="test")
    await tst(rith)
    rith.start_new.assert_called_with("durable_orchestrator")

and in function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

rithapp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@rithapp.timer_trigger(schedule="0 */1 * * * *", arg_name="timer")
@rithapp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def rith_func(timer: func.TimerRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> None:
    await tst(client)
async def tst(client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> None:
    await client.start_new("durable_orchestrator")

Output:


While this doesn't solve your problem completely, I have found that to unit test decorated azure functions, I need to do this in my tests to correctly call a function.
replace:
result = await my_func(mock_timer_request, mock_starter)

with:
func_call = my_func.build().get_user_function()
result = await func_call(mock_request)

This will solve the "await" issue for all the tests I've seen in Azure Functions. I have not yet solved mocking the durable client. This will however work for any durable function activities, or regular azure function trigger types (timer, http, etc...)
Update:
It seems that the decorator for the durable client input is being wrapped when I imported my function into the unit test. By adding this right below my imports (I lifted the code from here):
class TestImageStitcherActivity(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Do cleanup first so it is ready if an exception is raised
        def kill_patches():  # Create a cleanup callback that undoes our patches
            patch.stopall()  # Stops all patches started with start()
            reload(uut)  # Reload our UUT module which restores the original decorator
        self.addCleanup(kill_patches)  # We want to make sure this is run so we do this in addCleanup instead of tearDown
        
        # Now patch the decorator where the decorator is being imported from
        patch('azure.durable_functions.decorators.durable_app.Blueprint.durable_client_input', lambda *x, **y: lambda f: f).start()  # The lambda makes our decorator into a pass-thru. Also, don't forget to call start()          
        reload(uut)  # Reloads the uut.py module which applies our patched decorator

(Note that I am using a blueprint, so that's what I am patching.)
I was able to successfully mock the durable_client_input and get respones. An example test for me contains this:
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @patch('routes.submit.generate_confirmation_id', side_effect=Exception("Error generating confirmation ID"))
    async def test_submit_generate_confirmation_id_error(self, mock_generate_confirmation_id):
        mock_durable_client = MagicMock()
        mock_durable_client.start_new = AsyncMock(return_value="instance_id_123")

    <normal test here>

